# Trailing hyphen not included in tag search

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

Searching for "status" and "status-" returns the same results.  To see only the red moderator tags, one must search for "status--".  Wondering if this is by-design or not?

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/5161/captureqcm.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/5161/captureqcm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design -- we search for both hyphenated and non-hyphenated forms of the tag simultaneously because users tend to enter it both ways.